# retrieving data from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a sign up page that has input boxes where you would enter your name, email address and password. After submitting that form there is a sign in page where it checks to see if you are in the database by `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$_POST[name]' AND email = '[email]'`. This all works fine, but when you actually get into the site on your account i want to have a message at the top that says 'Welcome back (name from database). To do this i used `$name = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = $email");` and had `<?php echo $name ?>` at the top. This won't work though. Why?

Comment: post a bit more of your code, so that we could know that how are you accessing and displaying data

Comment: You need to read, learn and understand the right tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

"mysql_query" has been deprecated, you want to use "mysqli_query" now. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

To answer your question, performing the query creates an array, you need to followup on that by fetching from the array.

If you are doing this in a procedural style then the final code should look something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password"); // connect to the database
$query="SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'"; // create the query. Note the quotes arounds the email variable.
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query); // run the query
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result); // fetch the array that is returned from the query
$name=$row['first_name']; // assign the first_name field to the $name variable

echo "Hello ".$name.","; // output the variable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: Small correction...  you don't want to store **passwords** as plain text. There should be no problem keeping data such as usernames and email addresses in plain text.

Comment: @MikeEverhart I had read a post some time ago suggesting storing any personal identification information in a secure manner (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271376/should-i-keep-email-addresses-as-plaintext-in-database). This being my first post, I didn't want to rock the boat by telling someone to do something insecure with personal data. But having read more on the subject, I have decided I was being overly cautious, and I agree with you. I've edited the suggestion out of my answer. Thanks!